# Weka, load in model, but no model has been built yet

Tags: java, eclipse, model, weka, random-forest

Recently I am responsible for load in a WEKA Random Forest model and use that model to do some work. However, I can load in the model, but the when I print it out, it says:

```
RandomTree: no model has been built yet.
```

It repeats this for 30 times since the model is a random forest of 30 trees.
I do not understand why the forest is there (since I can load in), but the trees of the forest are gone.

Originally, I have met some errors of serialVersionUID, then I simply changed two lines of the WEKA code, could this lead to the fact that now the serialVersionUID of Random Forest is correct, but the serialVersionUID of the trees in it are still not compatible the Eclipse does not report?
What else could it be?

Thank you very much ahead!

Comment: Can you provide the code that builds/generates the tree? The relevant parts?

Comment: Hi, CommuSoft, I can't. It is not built by me and that is a real problem.